Adding logo image on navbar on MkDocs - default theme
I have a MkDocs project using the default theme and linked the logo image under the theme, like below
theme:   
  name: mkdocs   
  logo: img/logo.png

When I run the project I dont see the logo icon in the navigation bar. How do I add the logo icon on the navigation bar?
I made sure the name of the icon is correct and there are no typos.
